# ¿Cómo validar que no haya un mínimo de caracteres pero sí un máximo?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy preparando una expresión regular:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{20}
```

Hasta el momento estoy con la parte previa del "@" de un email y estoy tratando de hacer algo como esto:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{"*"-20}
```

Donde aparece "*" trato de poner que no tenga un tamaño mínimo, pero sí un máximo

¿Como podría montar la expresión?

La idea es usarlo luego para hacer esto:
Correo electrónico en formato varios caracteres (letras, números, puntos o guiones altos o bajos, 20 máximo) seguido de arroba, letras (20 máximo), punto (1), y 2 o 3 letras.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La solución es usar [`{n,m}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-quantifier) (`cuantificador de rango`), donde `n` es el mínimo de ocurrencias posibles y `m` el máximo.

Ejemplo:

```js
var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,20}$/;

console.log(re.test('')); // 0 chars
console.log(re.test('1')); // 1 chars
console.log(re.test('12345678901234567890'));// 20 chars
console.log(re.test('123456789012345678901'));// 21 chars
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta ;D